# How to accurately retrieve the list of active subscriptions in Android billing library 6

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I'm developing an Android app that utilizes in-app subscriptions using the `Google Play Billing Library 6.0.0`. My goal is to retrieve the list of active subscriptions and accurately determine their status, including whether they are set to auto-renew or have been canceled.

I'm currently using the following code to query the purchases and check the auto-renewing flag:

```
billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(
    QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder()
        .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
        .build(),
    new PurchasesResponseListener() {
        public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(
            @NonNull BillingResult billingResult,
            @NonNull List<Purchase> purchases) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
                for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                    if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED && purchase.isAutoRenewing()) {
                        // Active subscription
                    } else {
                        // Expired or canceled subscription
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Failed to retrieve purchases
            }
        }
    }
);
```

However, I'm experiencing inconsistent results. I have two devices, both use the same Google account. On the first device, `purchase.isAutoRenewing()` returns `true` even when there are no active subscriptions, while on the other device, it seems to work correctly.

I would like to ensure that I'm retrieving the list of active subscriptions accurately, regardless of device or app status. Is there a recommended approach or best practice to achieve this?

Should I implement server-side checks using the Google Play Developer API to periodically update the subscription status? If so, how can I set up the server-side component(`nodejs`) and efficiently synchronize the data with the app?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that in an article:
It is essential to keep in mind that relying solely on the information provided by the client-side library may not always be sufficient when working with in-app subscriptions and checking their status using the Google Play Billing Library. The library's data can sometimes be inconsistent or take a while to return. Utilizing the Google Play Developer API for server-side checks is recommended in order to guarantee a subscription status that is both accurate and dependable.

You can periodically check the status of subscriptions and synchronize the data with your app by using server-side checks. Using Node.js, you can generally set up the server-side component in the following way:

1. Set up a server with Node.js: To manage the server-side logic, you will require a server. A Node.js framework like Express.js can be used to build an HTTP server that can handle Android app requests.
2. Utilize the Google Play Developer API to sign in: Follow the documentation given by Google to verify your server with the Google Play Designer Programming interface. This involves establishing the authentication flow in your server-side code and acquiring the necessary credentials.
3. Set up an endpoint to check the status of a subscription: Make a Programming interface endpoint on your server that your Android application can call to actually look at the situation with memberships. The user's subscription status and authentication with the Google Play Developer API should be handled by this endpoint.
4. Integrate your app with subscription information: Make a request to the server-side endpoint to obtain the most recent subscription status for the user whenever the Android app starts or other relevant events, such as user login, occur. Based on the server response, update the local subscription data for your application.
5. Occasionally update membership status: On your server, implement a scheduler or background task to periodically update the subscription status of all active users. This guarantees that your application's information stays cutting-edge regardless of whether the client effectively open the application.

You can have more control over subscription status verification and guarantee accurate results regardless of device or app status by implementing server-side checks. Reduce reliance on potentially inconsistent client-side data by using the server-side component as a true source of truth for subscription data.

Make sure your Android app provides appropriate error messages or fallback behaviors to handle any failures or errors that may occur during the server-side checks.

Note: A general outline for setting up a server-side component for subscription status checks can be found in the aforementioned steps. You might have to allude to the authority Google Play Designer Programming interface documentation for more unambiguous execution subtleties and best practices.

Comment: Is there any quota limit the developer API?

Comment: After a quick google search I found out that the quota is: 200,000 queries per day

Answer (score 2):

Use `Google Play Developer API`. This API provides functionality not available in the Google Play Billing Library, such as securely verifying purchases and issuing refunds to your users

You can set up a `server-side component` using `Node.js` and use the Google Play Developer API to periodically update the subscription status. You can then synchronize the data with your app to ensure that you are retrieving the list of active subscriptions accurately.

--Link your `Google Play Developer Account to a Google Cloud Project`

--Enable the `Google Play Developer API` for your linked Google Cloud Project

--Authorize an `API key` for the Google Play Developer API in your linked Google Cloud Project

--Set up a `service account` with appropriat`e Google Play Console` permissions to access the `Google Play Developer API`

You can then use the [`authorized API key and service account`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started) to make requests to the Google Play Developer API from your Node.js server-side component.

Yes, Google Developer `APIs` have quota limits.

The specific quota limits for each API can vary depending on factors such as the type of API, the specific method or action being performed, the user's account type (e.g., free or paid), and any additional quotas or limits that may be imposed on a per-project or per-user basis.

To determine the quota limits for a specific Google Developer API, you can refer to the API's documentation. Each API typically provides information about the available quotas, including the number of requests per day, rate limits (requests per minute or second), and any specific quotas or limits for certain API features.

You can also monitor your API usage and check the current status of your quotas through the Google Cloud Console or the API Console, depending on the API you are using

Comment: Is there any quota limit the developer API?

Comment: yes  ✅ they are thee ...  refer to updated answer for more details